# Create dynamic fields in ModelForm (Django)

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I create fields in ModelForm on the go?

For example, I want to create 3 textboxes `(because there are 3 entries in the database table)`

```
 ID  Name   Value 
------------------
 1   Alpha  10   
 2   Beta   91    
 3   Char   800
```

How do I display it in this way to the user? Does it involve the **_init** definition? Is it possible to do a for loop of objects in your model form class to retrieve its values and convert them to a field to be displayed? Appreciate any suggestions.

```
Alpha 

[textbox]
______
Beta

[textbox]

____

etc..

[Submit]
```

Here is what I tried to do in the def init of the modelform:

```
self.fields['myfield'].widget = forms.Textarea()
```

Can't seem to give me the output, do mind my weak understanding of certain django concepts.

Answer (score 18):

I think that your best bet is, in this case, to stick to [Model formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).
For any other case, you can just append new fields to the `fields` attribute, inside your form's `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.update({
        'foo': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea()),
        'bar': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea()),
    })
```

Remember that, in this case, you have to call the parent's `__init__` first, so you'll have the `.fields` available.

Comment: Formsets are the simple answer here.

Answer (score 7):

You can also dynamically define form fields using the `django.forms.models.ModelFormMetaclass` (used by django.forms.models.modelform_factory). This will create a ModelForm class using the fields you specify rather than updating the fields 'on the fly' in the init.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import ModelForm, ModelFormMetaclass


model = MyModel
fields = {
    'myfield': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
}

meta_attrs = {
    'model': model,
}

Meta = type('Meta', (object, ), meta_attrs)

form_class_attrs = {
    'Meta': Meta, 
}

form_class_attrs.update(fields)

MyModelForm = ModelFormMetaclass('MyModelForm', (ModelForm, ), form_class_attrs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you want to override the `__init__`, something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for foo, bar in jelly:
        self.fields[foo] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

See lots more info [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) - it all pretty much applies to ModelForm as well.

Comment: You can add queryset to the forms.CharField to get retrieve the values from database dynamically